# Cannot find module 'project directory' using node + webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

I've provided my `webpack.config.js` and `package.json` below. I've tried reinstalling the `node_modules`, but I don't think that's the issue seeing as it's the entire project it's not finding. I'm fairly new to webpack and I think it's a problem with the webpack configuration.

Any help would be appreciated.

I'm getting this error when I try to build and start the application.

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\code\project-name'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

This is the `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node',

  entry: {
    app: ['babel-polyfill', './src/app.js']
  },

  output: {
    path: './dist/',
    filename: '[name].js'
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /.js$/,
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  }
}
```

This is the `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "./dist/app.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build:watch": "webpack --colors --progress --watch",
    "build": "webpack --colors --progress",
    "start": "node ."
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "standard": {
    "parser": "babel-eslint"
  },
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "latest",
      "stage-0"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.17.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.5",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-latest": "^6.16.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.16.0",
    "standard": "^8.4.0",
    "webpack": "^1.13.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.16.4"
  }
}
```

This is the `app.js`

```
console.log('test')
```

Edit:

Here is the file structure of the project.

```
project-name/
    src/
        app.js
    webpack.config.js
    package.json
    node_modules/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `start` script you run `node .`, which means to run the module of the current directory. So node sees that there is a `package.json` and looks for the `main` property and tries to run it. What you really do is run `node ./dist/app.js`, but that file doesn't exist.

You need to build it first, so webpack actually creates that file:

```
npm run build
```

You may have run `npm build`, which is an npm built-in command and does not run your script.

Comment: ....I was really hoping it wasn't just me being stupid, but alas. Thanks for noticing that.

Comment: So just to clarify, `npm run start` is doing the same thing as my `npm start`, but since `npm build` is a built-in command, I need to do `npm run build` to specify that I'm running a script I've defined?

Comment: Yeah exactly. Although `npm start` is just a special case that runs `npm run start` and you can't run any arbitrary script without using `run` . But for instance [Yarn](https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn) allows you to do that, so the strategy is when running `yarn <cmd>` it will check if `<cmd>` is a built-in command of yarn and runs it, otherwise it will try to run the script specified in `package.json`.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for your help!